# merge 2 rows into 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, gaps-and-islands

I want to merge every 2 rows into a single a row

table: clock_activities

```
id      employee_id   activity     created_at
1       1             start_break  1:00
2       1             end_break    1:10
3       1             start_break  2:00
4       1             end_break    2:10
5       1             start_break  2:30
6       1             end_break    2:45        
7       1             start_break  3:10
8       1             end_break    3:20
```

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
start    end       total
1:00     1:10      00:10
2:00     2:10      00:10
2:30     2:45      00:15
3:10     3:20      00:10
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I couldn't find anything on Stackoverflow that had these same requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a self join:

```
select c1.employee_id, 
  c1.created_at `start`, min(c2.created_at) `end`,
  time_format(timediff(
    min(c2.created_at),
    c1.created_at
  ), "%H:%i") total
from clock_activities c1 inner join clock_activities c2
on c1.employee_id = c2.employee_id
and c1.activity = 'start_break' and c2.activity = 'end_break'
and c1.created_at < c2.created_at
group by c1.employee_id, c1.created_at
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uwpCE1wKouhNfMJmYx6Urf/2).
Results:

```
| employee_id | start | end  | total |
| ----------- | ----- | ---- | ----- |
| 1           | 1:00  | 1:10 | 00:10 |
| 1           | 2:00  | 2:10 | 00:10 |
| 1           | 2:30  | 2:45 | 00:15 |
| 1           | 3:10  | 3:20 | 00:10 |
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this with a window sum that defines the groups of records: everytime a `'start_break'` is seen, a new group starts. You can then aggregate:

```
select 
    employee_id,
    min(case when id = 'start_break' then created_at end) start_break,
    max(case when id = 'end_break' then created_at end) end_break,
    timestampdiff(
        minute, 
        max(case when id = 'end_break' then created_at end),
        min(case when id = 'start_break' then created_at end)
    ) total_minutes
from (
    select t.*, sum(activity = 'start_break') over(partition by employee_id order by id) grp
    from mytable t
)
group by employee_id, grp
```

Answer (score 0):

For each start you can get the next end using window functions:

```
select employee_id, time, created_at as start_time, end_time,
       timestamp_diff(second, start_time, end_time)
from (select t.*,
             min(case when activity = 'end_break' then created_at end) over (partition by employee_id order by created_at desc) as end_time
      from t
     ) t
where activity = 'start_break';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select id,  min(activity='start_break')
      Over (partition by id<=id%2), 
     Min(activity='end_break')Over 
     (partition by id<=id%2),
     Min(Case when 
       activity='end_break' then 
      Date end) - Min(Case when 
       activity='start_break' then 
      Date end)Over (partition by 
       id<=id%2)
     From table
```